# WebClient HttpClient Upload From WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient, webclient.uploaddata

Seriously i search a lot upload file from WP8 to server. it's doesn't work :(

Why i get this error?? it's the error is because my FileuploadUrl?
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

```
 private async void UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (photoStream != null)
            {
                 //var fileUploadUrl = @"http://<IPaddress>:<port>/fileupload";
                var fileUploadUrl = @"http://www.comevox.com:80/services";
                var client = new HttpClient();
                photoStream.Position = 0;

                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "file", fileName);

                await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)
                    .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                    {
                        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    });
            }

            btnUpload.IsEnabled = false;
            imgSelectedImage.Source = null;
            txtMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        catch
        {
            txtError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the request to the right URL? Do you have to rights to post something over there?

Comment: i want to post something in my folder...How should i check whether got rights to post somehting over there?

Answer (score 0):

> Fixing 405 errors - general
>
> 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to
>   introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs
>   allow the POST method necessary to process the form.
>
> All 405 errors can be traced to configuration of the Web server and
>   security governing access to the content of the Web site, so should
>   easily be explained by your ISP.

[Reference](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)